# Test # of Objects in Array

Tags: arrays, json, object, testing, postman

As you can see in the following json, I am running tests and I cannot figure out the last one. I need to be able to count the # of objects that are in an array to ensure the correct # were returned in the response body. Test3 needs to return 100 objects in its array.

**My Tests:**

```
pm.test('Test Scenario 1', function(){
pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.test('Test Scenario 2', function(){
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect (jsonData.Test1).is.to.equal("XYZ");
});

pm.test('Test Scenario 3', function(){
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect (jsonData.Test2).is.to.equal(XYX);
});

const schema = {
type: "object",
Properties:{
Test1: {"type":"object"},
Test2: {"type": "object"},
Test3:{
type: "array",
}
},
required: ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
}
};

pm.test("Test Scenario 4", () => {
pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema);
})

pm.test("Test Scenario 5", function(){
pm.response.json().Test3.length >= 100;
})
```

**The response body looks like so:**

```
{ "Test1" : XYZ, 
"Test2" : "XYX", 
"Test 3" :  [ 
{ "variable1" : "variable1output", 
"variable2" : "variable2output", 
"variable3" : "variable3output", 
"variable4" : "variable1output" 
} , 
{ "variable1" : "variable1output", 
"variable2" : "variable2output", 
"variable3" : "variable3output", 
"variable4" : ""variable4output" } , 
] 
}
```

Comment: `pm.expect(pm.response.json().Test3.length).to.equal(100);`? I would double check the schema test and make sure you see that fails too, doesn't look quite right.

Comment: It does fail. Just can't get the object count to work

Comment: OK, did the assertion that I added work for the count? You have greater than or equal 100 in your example, does it need to be above 100?

Comment: I just need the object count to equal a # I give it. In this case, I put 100. and I didn't put my full response body.

Comment: So did the assertion that I added work?

Comment: Hi Danny, it did not work. I put the correct # to be expected and it failed with the Postman message of: ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: Wait! I think it works! Just rechecked and I had a typo! Let me do some fail examples in the mock to ensure.

Comment: It works! Thank you!